# Getting "[Unresolved compilation problem: Type mismatch: cannot convert from TreeMap<String,String> to String]"

Tags: java, treemap

I'm new in Java. Please help me

[This is my restful controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6LXQo.png)

[This is the model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHBYy.png)

[The error when I run the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QbdD.png)

Comment: Please don't post images of text. Edit your question and add the relevant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your controller return type is `String`, and it return getGadaianDetails(), but method getGadaianDetails return type is TreeMap.

you can make your controller return type as `TreeMap`, this may require re-agreement with the front-end on the data structures that interact.

Or, you can modify the implementation of the getGadaianDetails method so that it returns a string